# $P$ is a probability function assigns probability $p(0<p<1)$ to each point set of $\Omega$.Show that $\Omega$ must have a finite number of points.

Tags: probability-theory

Let $(\Omega ,A ,P)$ be a probability space,where $A$ is the sigma field of all subsets of $\Omega$ and $P$ is a probability function that assigns probability $p(0<p<1)$ to each point set of $\Omega$.Show that $\Omega$ must have a finite number of points.

I dont know, perhaps, I am citing an example. If $\Omega$ is infinite and uncountable, suppose the real line $\mathbb{R}$, the we shall take $A$ as the class of all Borel sets of $\mathbb{R}$

But I don't how to prove the problem rigorously.

Comment: Are you saying that $\mathbb{P}(\{\omega\})=p$ for every $\omega\in\Omega$?

Comment: that's what the question says

Comment: Well if $\Omega$ contains a countably infinite subset $E$, then $\mathbb{P}(E)=\sum_{\omega\in E}\mathbb{P}(\{\omega\})=\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

We must have $p|\Omega| = 1 $, hence $p = {1 \over |\Omega|}$.